# How to compile a program from .cpp files and a makefile

Tags: c++, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I recently downloaded a program. A patient specific survival prediction CLI, http://pssp.srv.ualberta.ca/

The readme included states:
    "1 Compilation
The code should compile on Linux without any modification. To compile, just type ’make’. There should
be 2 executables after compilation, mtlr train and mtlr test."

I download an extracted the folder to my location, when I go into the directory and type make I get:

```
x@x-laptop:/pssp_source$ make
g++ -c -O3 DenseVector.cpp -o DenseVector.o
In file included from DenseVector.cpp:1:0:
DenseVector.h:9:2: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
  size_t m_dim; 
  ^
DenseVector.h:18:21: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘n’
  DenseVector(size_t n); 
                     ^
DenseVector.h:26:33: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
  double const& operator[](const size_t i) const
                                 ^
DenseVector.h:26:40: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘i’ with no type [-fpermissive]
  double const& operator[](const size_t i) const
                                        ^
DenseVector.h:31:27: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
  double& operator[](const size_t i)
                           ^
DenseVector.h:31:34: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘i’ with no type [-fpermissive]
  double& operator[](const size_t i)
                                  ^
DenseVector.h:38:2: error: ‘size_t’ does not name a type
  size_t dim() const
  ^
DenseVector.h: In member function ‘void DenseVector::push_back(double)’:
DenseVector.h:23:3: error: ‘m_dim’ was not declared in this scope
   m_dim++; 
   ^
DenseVector.cpp: At global scope:
DenseVector.cpp:6:1: error: prototype for ‘DenseVector::DenseVector(size_t)’ does not match any in class ‘DenseVector’
 DenseVector::DenseVector(size_t n): m_dim(n)
 ^
In file included from DenseVector.cpp:1:0:
DenseVector.h:5:7: error: candidates are: DenseVector::DenseVector(const DenseVector&)
 class DenseVector
       ^
DenseVector.h:12:2: error:                 DenseVector::DenseVector()
  DenseVector(void);
  ^
DenseVector.cpp: In constructor ‘DenseVector::DenseVector()’:
DenseVector.cpp:16:2: error: class ‘DenseVector’ does not have any field named ‘m_dim’
 :m_dim(0)
  ^
DenseVector.cpp: In member function ‘void DenseVector::clear()’:
DenseVector.cpp:27:22: error: ‘m_dim’ was not declared in this scope
   for (size_t i=0; i<m_dim; i++)
                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cassert:43:0,
                 from DenseVector.cpp:3:
DenseVector.cpp: In function ‘double sprod_nn(const DenseVector&, const DenseVector&)’:
DenseVector.cpp:37:11: error: ‘const class DenseVector’ has no member named ‘dim’
  assert(a.dim() == b.dim());
           ^
DenseVector.cpp:37:22: error: ‘const class DenseVector’ has no member named ‘dim’
  assert(a.dim() == b.dim());
                      ^
DenseVector.cpp:38:15: error: ‘const class DenseVector’ has no member named ‘dim’
  size_t n = a.dim(); 
               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cassert:43:0,
                 from DenseVector.cpp:3:
DenseVector.cpp: In function ‘void multadd_nn(DenseVector&, const DenseVector&, double)’:
DenseVector.cpp:49:11: error: ‘class DenseVector’ has no member named ‘dim’
  assert(w.dim()==a.dim());
           ^
DenseVector.cpp:49:20: error: ‘const class DenseVector’ has no member named ‘dim’
  assert(w.dim()==a.dim());
                    ^
DenseVector.cpp:50:15: error: ‘class DenseVector’ has no member named ‘dim’
  size_t n = w.dim();
               ^
DenseVector.cpp: In function ‘void smult_n(DenseVector&, double)’:
DenseVector.cpp:62:15: error: ‘class DenseVector’ has no member named ‘dim’
  size_t n = w.dim(); 
               ^
make: *** [DenseVector.o] Error 1
```

The contents of the folder look like:

```
x@x-laptop:/pssp_source$ ls
common.cpp  data_type_api.h  DenseVector.h  Main.cpp  Makefile    Sparm.cpp  Sparm.o           SparseVector.h  test_model.mltr  Util.h
common.h    DenseVector.cpp  example_data   Main.o    readme.pdf  Sparm.h    SparseVector.cpp  Test.cpp        test_model.mlty
```

I looked up the basic packages needed for compiling c++ code, as well as basics on how to run it and none have gotten me past this issue. It looks as if it has a problem with size_t not having a type.

The start of DenseVector.cpp is :

```
#include "DenseVector.h"

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

DenseVector::DenseVector(size_t n): m_dim(n)
{
  m_dvector.reserve(n);
  for (size_t i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
          m_dvector.push_back(0);
  }
}
```

I have never compiled code like this before, so I am probably missing something obvious. If its needed I am running ubuntu 14.04, g++ version is
4.8.4.

Thanks

Comment: `size_t` is a member of `std`.  You need `std::size_t`.

Comment: [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) comes out of `<cstddef>` and requires the `std::` namespace

Comment: [size_t can not be found by g++-4.1 or others on Ubuntu 8.1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107940/size-t-can-not-be-found-by-g-4-1-or-others-on-ubuntu-8-1)

Comment: @CoryKramer: Or you use `<stddef.h>` and don't need `std::`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the README lied.  Probably it happened to work with a different version of the standard library.

Try adding

```
#include <stddef.h>
```

near the top of DenseVector.h.

Comment: @slips [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `DenseVector.h` in the root directory of the program and modify it, inserting

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>  // <--- Add this line to the file

class DenseVector
{
   protected:
// ...
```

Save it and try again!

Comment: That'll put `size_t` in `std::` - so it won't be found.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using the correct version of `C`; I think you need C11. Instead of using the `-03` flag, use `-11` or `-std=c11`. Then recompile it.